# Processing JS Bin Score and Accelerator

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, processing, jsbin

```java
int objectX = width/2;
int objectY = 200;
int snelheidY = 1;
int score = 0;
int richting = 1;
int positiebal;
int bal = ellipse(objectX, objectY, 50, 50);

void setup() 
{ 
size(400, 400);
positiebal = height/2
textSize(12);
}


void draw() {
background(0, 0, 0);

ellipse(positiebal, objectY, 50, 50);

if(objectY > 375) 
snelheidY = -snelheidY;

if(objectY<25)
snelheidY = -snelheidY

objectY = objectY + snelheidY;

text("score = " +score,4,10);

}

void mousePressed()
{

if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, positiebal, 200)<=200)
{score=score+1;
snelheidY = snelheidY+1
}
}
```

""""""""""""""""""""""""""

I have the following questions:
1. The ball is accelerated by presing on it when it is going down, but it doesn't seem to work when the ball is going up.
2. The score system should only go up when the ball is pressed, but it doesn't do that.

Can someone with further knowledge please explain these following questions?

Answer (score 0):

> The ball is accelerated by presing on it when it is going down, but it doesn't seem to work when the ball is going up.

The code your posted accelerates the ball **downwards** whenever you press the mouse. That happens in this line:

```
snelheidY = snelheidY+1;
```

If the ball is moving upwards, then accelerating it downwards will look like decelerating it until it stops. If you keep pressing then it will turn around and go downwards.

If you want the ball to accelerate in the direction it's going, then you're going to have to add some logic here. Maybe use an `if` statement to check which direction the ball is going, or maybe use multiplication instead of addition.

> The score system should only go up when the ball is pressed, but it doesn't do that.

Nothing in your code checks that. You're always increasing the score whenever the user presses the mouse, as long as the cursor is 200 pixels away from the ball. If you want to check whether the mouse is inside the ball, you should use the ball's radius instead of 200.

You should also really get into the habit of [debugging](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your program. It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions. It's much easier if you try something, write some code, and then ask about a specific piece of code that's misbehaving.